# Having a huge list of numbers and an order with unique order numbers, how to make both O(1) accessible?

Tags: java, data-structures

Imagine I have a huge list with values

```
123
567
2355
479977
....
```

These are say ordered ascending

so

```
123 - 1
567 - 2
2355 - 3
479977 - 4
...
```

I want to have a **single** object that gives me access with the order number (1 or 2 or 3 ...) for the value, as well as with the actual value (123 or 567 or ...) for the order number. Does a structure like this exist?

**EDIT:** insertions and deletions should be possible.
If I have 2 Hashmaps, I need twice the memory and have to perform the operations twice.

Comment: Does your sequence need to support insertions and deletions, or is it fixed in advance? How many numbers will be in the sequence? Will the sequence always be numbers, or can they be anything?

Comment: Why do you care that it's a single object, as opposed to one mapping in each direction?  I suppose you could do it with a Guava `BiMap` if third-party libraries are allowed, but it might be easier to have a `List` and a `Map` separately.

Comment: For static list: array is what you are looking for, though in that case you will only have O(log(n)) for the lookup of order.

Comment: Huge means: offline algorithm? Do you have to store it in a file or other storage?

Comment: AlexWien, you are wrong: maintaining a list and hashmap gives you O(1)

Comment: for value to order: No hashmap is not O(1). It is amortized .... for order to value, this cleary is O(1)

Comment: @templatetypedef insertions and deletions should be allowed

Comment: @LouisWasserman I added an edit

Comment: finally I came to the conclusion, the  OP asked the wrong question if this code shall be used in practise, then demanding O(1) for fun makes no sense. O(1) tells nothing about actual speed performance nor memory usage. So what is best in your case depends on the number of elements, amount of searches, amount of inserts and deletions, dynamic or static data how and often that search is performed. In most cases it does not matter, any working soultion is sufficient, unless used in embedded systems or with realy huge data sets, or when extecuted e.g 1000 times a second.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a `ArrayList<Integer>` which has O(1) index lookup to store all your ints and the (index -> int) relationship and a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` which also has O(1) lookup to store the (int -> index) relationship.

Doing so, you have O(1) for each lookup direction.

Comment: If both fits in the memory I think this is the fastest solution.

Comment: Hashmap is not O(1). It is with a specific probabiliyt O(1). But not always. while an array access (your first part) is O(1)

Comment: Big O notation estimates complexity, not speed. I am not comparing with the speed of binary search in an array but on a large quantity of random ints, it will definitely scale better than O(log(n)). By definition.

Comment: I say the compexity of an hashmapo is not O(1) I never talked about speed!. It is O(1) with a specific probability, which id dependent of the datta to be inserted nd the used hash function. Study hashmaps. there is an detailed discussion here on SO.

Comment: I say the compexity of a hashmap is not O(1) I never talked about speed!. It is O(1) with a specific probability, which is dependent on the data to be inserted and the used hash function used. Study hashmaps. there is an detailed discussion here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have multiple datastructures, I would recommend having 2 Maps  :

1) Since the data is in an Array, you can directly access the values present at a given order (position). considering the update in the question that insertions and deletions need to supported, this can be achieved by using a HashMap where key = order, value = value at that order

2) Another reverse HashMap where key = value , value = order

Then you can have O(1) lookup time for both the cases.

Comment: @AlexWien Thanks for pointing out, I had assumed that the data is stored in a Map

Comment: Given the update to the question stating that the sequence should support insertions and deletions, I don't believe this meets the time bounds.

Comment: @templatetypedef In that case we can achive the desired result by converting the First Array to a map and then insertions and deletions can happen in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like a `HashMap`. You can read about them on Oracle's website: [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I see why a `HashMap` would be useful here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @templatetypedef what I gathered from the question is that he's asking for a way to associate the number with its position in the list. HashMap's could do this. Assigning one value as the key (position in the list) and the number as the value.

Comment: how would I get the index (the order number) when having the value?

Comment: They are linked to each other. The index (would be the key in your hashmap) and that would be paired with the value(the number).

Answer (score 0):

Answer for static data:

O(1) is not possible for value to order. (A hashmap has not true O(1) compexity)
But O(1) is easy for order to value.

About value to order:
The Order will be about log2(N). You need either a binary search (log2 (n)) or a hashmap with similar effort. I expect the binSearch to be the fastest (less Object overhead) when using the standard HashMap implementation, where you map the number with its order value.
Update: Why the binary Search:
With binary search you find the array position of the element, which is equal to the order. This does not need any additonal memory, and need far less memory than the std hashMap implementation.

for dynamic data, it depens how often one inserts and how often one searches.
for high number of searches and few insertions I wouldstay with Array(List).

About order to value:

Simply store values ascening in an array (Or ArrayList) a[]; a[orderNr] gives the value.

.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't understand what you're describing here. Can you elaborate about what the binary search would be for?

Comment: binary serach gives the array index of the element to be search, whichb is equivalent to the order.

Comment: Dynamic: arraylist is not so good when there are inserts in the middle or the beginning. If only larger elements than previous elements inserted, that is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, you are correct., But this was not the question. It was not asked for insertion complexity. only for search. So the ideal strcuture has to consider the data size amnd the number of insert, deletions and searches. which is unknownin thsi question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sorted Tree, you can get log(n) time for both. Understanding that O(log(n)) is not O(1), it's definitely on the order of. For instance if you have 4 billion elements, it would be 1 (theoretically, though not always) vs 32.

If you need both to be O(1), you should create an array of sorted ints / longs / BigIntegers or whatever you need for lookup one way, and then a HashMap of ints / longs / BigIntegers to its position index

Comment: Sorted tree alternative might be skiplists, more cache-friendly.